# Generate new variable in one dataset using observation from another dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

I have two datasets, one with one observation and two variables. Other dataset with 10 observations, four variables.

Dataset 1

Final   Result

X Fail

Dataset 2

A   B   C   D    Output

1   1   2   Pass
2   1   2   Pass
3   1   2   Pass
4   1   2   Fail
5   1   2   Pass
6   1   2   Fail
7   1   2   Pass
8   1   2   Fail
9   1   2   Pass
10  1   2   Pass

I would like to generate a fifth variable (output) in the second dataset depending on the value of the second variable in the first dataset.

If Result in first dataset equal to fail, generate a new variable output in the second dataset as fail. If Result in first dataset equal to pass, then generate a new variable output in the second dataset which will be equal to the value in column D of the second dataset.

Comment: Do not post data has pictures.  Post it as text.  Preferable as a SAS dataset than can be run to re-create the dataset.

Comment: Hi @Tom, I edited the question, posted text, removed pictures. The first row for each dataset is the variable name, from second row are the observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some simple IF/THEN logic.  Since you know DATASET1 only has one observation then only read one observation from it.

```
data want;
  if _n_=1 then set dataset1 ;
  set dataset2 ;
  length OUTPUT $4 ;
  if RESULT='FAIL' then OUTPUT=RESULT;
  else OUTPUT=D ;
run;
```